# Submitting Data from Outputted SQL Table to Another Table in Database Using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

UPDATE FIXED: I changed the jQuery $('#insertsimtocom').click(function() { to function addthis () { and is called on button click.

I have a table on my webpage displaying the contents of one table in SQL Database. On the table being outputted there is a field called 'Quantity' and each cell in that field has a textbox and a button 'Add'. The user can enter quantity and when press add this submits it to another table in database.

But its not working.

This is the table being outputted on webpage...
        echo "";
        $sqlGet = "SELECT * FROM simplex_list";

```
    //Grab data from database
    $sqlSimplex = mysqli_query($connect , $sqlGet)or die("Error retrieving data!");

    //Loop to display all records on webpage in a table

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Product Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSimplex , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<input type='text' id='sim' name='simplexcode' readonly   value='" . $row['s_code'] . "'>";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['description'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='com' name='complexcode' value='$newProductID'>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='text' size='6' id='userqty' name='quantity' >";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo "<input type='submit' id='insertsimtocom' name='add' value='Add!'>";
        echo "</td></tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
```

And this is the PHP script...

This is my jQuery...

```
  $('#insertsimtocom').click(function() {
            var scode = $('#sim').val();
            var ccode = $('#com').val();
            var qty = $('#userqty').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'insertsimplextoc_comp.php',
                    data: 'complexcode=' + ccode + '$simplexcode=' +  scode + '&quantity=' + qty;, 

            });
    });
```

The data is not being submitted at all for some reason.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: @JayBlanchard not sure how to do that? Using safari

Comment: Press the F12 key and the developer tools, including the console, will be available to you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I put in an alert into jQuery so when the 'Add' button is clicked an alert would appear but it doesn't. You wouldn't mind looking at that part?

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console?